# Will the Orberby for an Icollection<> be performed on the database level or application level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 web application , and i have the folloiwng model class inside my .tt folder:-

```
public partial class Patient
{
    public Patient()
    {
        this.Visits = new HashSet<Visit>();
    }

    public int PatientID { get; set; }
   //code goes here...
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    **public virtual ICollection<Visit> Visits { get; set; }**
```

Then on the Controller class i wrote the following :-

```
public PartialViewResult ShowOther(int id, int skip, int take )
        {
                ViewBag.take = take;
                Patient patient = repository.GetPatient(id);
               **Visit visit = patient.Visits.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Skip(skip).Take(take).SingleOrDefault();**
//code goes here
```

So my question if wether the following Orderby `patient.Visits.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Skip(skip).Take(take).SingleOrDefault();` be performed on the application level (which means that all the visits object will be retrived from the database and then the orderby will be done on the application level) **OR** the Orderby will be performed on the database and only the intended Visit object will be passed to the application?

My `repository.GetPatient(id);` method looks as follow:-

```
 public Patient GetPatient(int id)
        {
            return entities.Patients.FirstOrDefault(d => d.PatientID == id);        }
```

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you access `patient.Visits` lazy loading will load **ALL** visits to you application. Everything will be done in your application.

If you want to load only single visit you try this:

```
entities.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var patient = entities.Patients.FirstOrDefault(d => d.PatientID == id);
var visit = ((EntityCollection<Visit>)patient.Visists).CreateSourceQuery()
                                                      .OrderByDescending(d => d.Date)
                                                      .SingleOrDefault();
                                                      .
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but does this means that the lazy loading will perform separate queries to retrieve all the related visits individually , OR all the related visits will be retrieved at the same time using a single query to the database??.

Comment: If you have single patient you will have one query for retrieving the patient and once you access its `Visits` one additional query will be executed to gets all visits for that patient. If you for example have collection of patients and you will access their Visits properties in loop you will get additional query for every patient.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `.ToList()`, `.Single()` - database level. After calling `.ToList()`, `.Single()` - application level.

---

In your specific example it doesn't matter as the call to `FirstOrDefault` in the repository method executes the query and returns the result.