# Entity Framework, filter in returned class the circular Icolleciton list immediately

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Exploring the wonderful world of REST services with the new MVC 4 framework.
I stumble upon the issue that in the returned JSON data i want to filter immediately without thouching the EF.

My Employee Class:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
Partial Public Class EMPLOYEE
    Public Property EM_ID As Long
    Public Property EM_FIRSTNAME As String
    Public Property EM_LASTNAME As String

    Public Overridable Property AS_EM As ICollection(Of AS_EM) = New HashSet(Of AS_EM)
End Class
```

My AS_EM Class

```
Partial Public Class AS_EM
    Public Property ASE_ID As Long
    Public Property ASE_STATUS As String
    Public Property ASE_MOVE As String
    Public Property ASE_WHEN As Date
    Public Property ASE_EM_FK As Long
    Public Overridable Property EMPLOYEE As EMPLOYEE
End Class
```

Simplified Diagram below.

[image: DBschema]

1 employee can have multiple assets assigned to him/her.

My EmployeeController is constructed like this

```
    Public Function getEmployeebyOW(ByVal OW As String) As EMPLOYEE

        Dim context1 As New amsadmEntities
        Dim result = (From e In context1.EMPLOYEE
                 Where e.EM_CORPID = OW
                 Select e
                 ).FirstOrDefault
        Return result
    End Function
```

When i run it, i get what i wanted, a json serialised Employee with all his asset history, both ACT(ive) and PAS(sive). Screenshot shows the first one with a PAS(ive) asset assignment

[image]

I would like to know how to filter directly the list of Asset Assignments so i get only the ASSET that have the ASE_STATUS="ACT" , apply that directly in the LINQ filter, without using anonymous types.

The only way i've found so far is to retrieve the Employee and his collection of asset assignments first and then drop it, filter that list and reattach.

```
    Public Function getEmployeebyOW(ByVal OW As String) As EMPLOYEE

        Dim context As New amsadmEntities
        Dim result = (From e In context.EMPLOYEE
                 Where e.EM_CORPID = OW
                 Select e
                 ).FirstOrDefault


        Dim goodentries As ICollection(Of AS_EM) =
               (From a In context.AS_EM
               Where a.ASE_EM_FK = result.EM_ID And a.ASE_STATUS = "ACT"
               Select a).ToList
        result.AS_EM.Clear()
        For j = 0 To goodentries.Count - 1
            result.AS_EM.Add(goodentries(j))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
```

Is there a better and faster way? Couldn't get my head around applying a Where condition on the Icollection in the main Linq query.

I want to keep the EF as it is as the Employee's Asset history is vital for other Controllers and Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to use two separate EF queries to load employee and its (theirs) active assets. If you execute those queries on the same context instance EF should automatically populate navigation properties.

If you need to load only single employee creating second query can be even automated by using [`EntityCollection.CreateSourceQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901553/will-the-orberby-for-an-icollection-be-performed-on-the-database-level-or-appl/10901621#10901621). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602371/entity-framework-4-how-to-cap-the-number-of-child-elements-from-another-table/5603857#5603857) are mentioned all typical options to filter navigation property.

Comment: Right,  I was looking for a 'magic linq query' inside the lazyloaded employee linq query directly but it makes sense to turn it off  in the 'GetEmployeeOW' function first and then just add the active devices to the Icollection ( disable lazyl-add active to icollection) instead of using lazyloading-clearing the Icollection results- and add them again.  Tnxs for pointing out.